# PHPUnit Selenium2 driver. closeWindow()

Tags: phpunit, selenium-webdriver

Can somebody explain to me why the testcase having closeWindow() function in the middle is failing with the communication to the server error, and another one doesn't:

FAILED:

```
public function test1()
{
    $this->url('http://www.yahoo.com');
    $this->closeWindow();             
    $this->url('http://www.google.com');

}
```

PASSED:

```
public function test1()
{
    $this->url('http://www.yahoo.com');                 
    $this->url('http://www.google.com');

}
```

closeWindow() is not suppose to clear the session unlike close(), right?

Comment: Which error do you get? And after closing the window, which window would you think is targeted for the next url() command? What would you expect?

Comment: I understand that in second case it's just re-using first window.What I'm trying to do is to close first browser window and open new window. Is possible to do in the same testcase? My goal is the cookie verification on new browser session.I would really appreciate your advice.

Comment: I can't help myself, but when I read such, I get the feeling that Selenium is used to test wrong things. If you want to verify cookie stuff, normally all you need is to fire some HTTP request and manage the cookies for you. Why to fire some command through some layer proxy layer to slash on a driver which then is remoting a browser for then somewhere in the verify some cookies? This sounds so totally crazy. Like running up 10 hills because well - no idea for what, maybe check if the hills are there? Keep in mind that Selenium is far away from perfect and very fragile. Don't do too much by it.

Comment: Well, I guess it was a reason of creating cookie functions in ALL Selenium WebDrivers. Seems they wanted to run 10 hills for nothing as well. Anyways, I've solved my problem. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I didn't say you can't test that, I just said it often looks like doing too much for that.